# Graph Theory Proof involving vertex degree

Tags: graph-theory

Show that every graph with two or more nodes contains two nodes that have equal degrees

Problem: The above claim is not completely true if self-loops are allowed. What should I do?

Comment: complain, maybe?

Comment: Just kidding, you should probably assume they aren't allowed and try the problem, then complain.

Comment: Not just loops, also multiple edges cause problems: you can draw a graph with three nodes of degrees one, two, and three. Also, there are infinite graphs in which no two nodes have the same degree. You need to assume a ***finite simple graph***.

Comment: Sometimes graphs without self loops are called *simple*, but other times undirected graphs are just assumed to be simple.